# auto-generated a domain class & controller according to a drag & drop interface

Tags: grails, groovy, drag-and-drop, auto-generate

I want to create a dynamic web application where the user has the opportunity to prepare its interfaces. This is equivalent to OpenERP but specific to a single domain.
I searched if grails allows me to do that.
I have tried to make calls to grails commands in code but I have concluded that this it is not possible to invoke a new class at runtime.

So, if someone has an idea, help me please.

Comment: Have you looked at the Dynamic Domain Class plugin for Grails?: http://grails.org/plugin/dynamic-domain-class

Comment: the plugin seems to be abandoned, and in the google group of the project the deveoper say that there is some important issue and he said we can't using it in production, and there is no evolution since 2011.